# LoRaWAN setup in Algeria

Tags: lorawan

I'm new to LoRaWAN. I want to set up a new gateway in my country (Algeria North Africa) since it has no gateways yet. I'm having some difficulties concerning finding the appropriate frequency and some similar problems. On the lora alliance website, I found that the suitable frequency for my region is 915MHz but when you start a new setup in thethingnetwork gateway, there is no router or frequency for my region?

- How to deal with that before buying a gateway?
- And for those who are from Morocco, Tunisia, Egypt, and other countries, how did you pick the suitable frequency?

Here are some images for context:

[image: my location]

[image: frequencies for my location]

[image: TTN frequencies]

[image: TTN touters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I've never set up a gateway so I might miss some details.

It seems to me that you know almost everything already. What I can understand with my broken french is that you should indeed be using 915MHz as the frequency as the other, 868MHz, isn't allowed in Algeria for use.

It is really sad seeing TheThingsNetwork completely forgets a continent but my solution would be to register it as if you are in the US. Because the frequency (and I'm guessing also the power limit) is equal.

And about your question for the router selection: I would suggest picking `ttn-router-eu`. I don't know what internet cables connect to Algeria but I'm guessing that the closest is probably a link to Europe and thus the lowest latency router would be Europe. In the grand scheme of things it probably doesn't matter much though.

Maybe you could also raise these issues on the thingsnetwork [forum](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/) as the frequency/region issue might just be that no one has put in the time/effort to add it to the options. For the router, it might even be possible to start running an application server/router for the ThingsNetwork so you can serve your region, but this is speculation on my part.

Comment: thank you Mr @tarick welling, for the answer

Comment: thank you Mr @tarick welling, for the answer. let's say that i bought the gateway, the nodes and i did the setup...now i want to send data from the nodes using arduino ide, to the gateway and from the gateway to a mosquitto mqtt server without passing through the TTN, is that possible ?? by programing the gateway to transfer the received data to my MQTT server instead of to forward it to TTN?
thank you in advence

Answer (score 0):

For Algeria you can use the frequency 433MHz, but unfortunately you are not authorized to use it without an authorization. You must apply for one from National Agency of Frequencies  ([www.anf.dz](http://www.anf.dz)) and it's a long procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Frequency Plans by Country: Algeria AS923_3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).